# Running class inside function

Tags: java

I am a new learner to Java; I want to run a class method inside a function thats not within the class scope inside VSC. However, my compiler tells me I have to remove the last curly braces from the class and require to instantiate the function as a method inside the class.

How do I use these in a dependent way?

For example:

```
import java.lang.Integer;

public class sortArray{

    public static void reorder(int[] T, int pos, int min){
        int i = 1;
        //int[] temp = new int[T.length];
        for( i = 1; i < T.length; i++){
            pos = i;
            min = T[i];
            for(int j = i+1; j < T.length; i++){
                if(Integer.compare(T[j], min) < 0){
                    pos=j;
                    min=T[j];
                    T[pos] = T[i];
                    T[i] = min; } }}}}


public static void read(){
    // run the class inside here
}
```

I come from a python background so best I explain from that background and correct me on the difference.

For example:

```
class sortArray:
    ....

def read():
    array = sortArray()
    reorder = array.reorder([1, 2, 3], 1, 1)
    return reorder
```

Comment: In java : a method HAS to be in a class. period

Comment: Looks like you just need to properly match your backets. What does "run the class" mean? Java has methods that run, not classes. Although there are Runnable classes that have a method run.

Comment: @matt I come from a python background so I am basing it from python interpretation. Something like `class sortArray: ...  a = sortArray()`. I have updated the post!

Comment: Right, you cannot override the "__call__" method of a class and expect to be able to use it like that. If you want to create an instance of `sortArray` use `sortArray x = new sortArray();` since you're using static methods you don't need an instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class SortArray{ //mind the class naming convention
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnotherClass.read(); //test purposes
    }
    public static void reorder(int[] T){
        for(int i = 0; i < T.length; i++){ //can declare inside loop
            int min = T[i];
            for(int j = i+1; j < T.length; j++){ //prob typo here, you increment i instead of j
                if(T[j] < min){ // no need for Integer.compare here
                    min =T[j];
                    T[j] = T[i];
                    T[i] = min;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class AnotherClass {
    public static void read(){
        int[] T = {4,3,3,5,9,7};
        // your call to the class aka static method, 
        // mind that the caller method also needs to be static
        SortArray.reorder(T); 
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(T));
    }
}
```

Output is `[3, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9]`

Answer (score 1):

From your python snippet, the equivalent java might look like this.

```
class Sorter{
    int[] reorder(int[] a, int pos, int min){
        return a;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
      Sorter s = new Sorter();
      int[] reorder = s.reorder( new int[]{1, 2, 3}, 1, 1 );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I use `extend` here so B extend A and so I inherent methods from A?

Comment: @teslajohn I don't know why you would. **static** methods are not inherited. Maybe you should go through a java tutorial and see a bit of how instance and class methods work. It shouldnt' take long if you have a python background and it will clarify quite a bit.

Comment: Good suggestion, I must have missed that part in the notes I was reading. I'll have another read from more detailed docs.

Comment: @teslajohn I tried to interpret your python code a bit. `public static void main(String[] args)` is an entry point to run the program. `new Sorter()` creates an instance of Sorter. "reorder" is no longer static. if it was you wouldn't *need* to create an instance. You could just say `Sorter.reorder(...)`